# How to use angle option when using ([angle=number]{node1} node2) notation?

Tags: pstricks

According to PSTricks manual, as shown in the screenshot below, there is an optional `angle` option.

[image]

Unfortunately, the example above does not show how to use `angle` option.

I have tried using `angle` but I always fail. The option does not affect anything.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}  
\usepackage{pst-eucl,multido}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+30}{3}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
    \pstGeonode(0,5){B}(3,3){A}
    \pstLineAB[nodesepB=-3]{B}{A}
    \pstCircleOA[Radius=\pstDistVal{1},linestyle=dashed]{A}{}
    \uput{1.5}[90](A){angle=$\i^\circ$}
    \psline[linecolor=blue]([offset=1,angle=\i]{B}A)% does not affect anything!
\end{pspicture}\hspace{5mm}}

\end{document}
```

How to use `angle` option when using `([angle=number]{node1} node2)` notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with current `pst-node.tex` version 1.29 from TL2013

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](10,10)
  \pnode(3,3){A}\psdot(A)\uput[-35](A){A}
  \pnode(6,5){B}\psdot(B)\uput[135](B){B}
  \psline[linestyle=dotted](A)\psline[linestyle=dotted](A)(B)
  \pscircle[linestyle=dotted](A){!5 sqrt}
  \pnode([nodesep=2]{B}A){P0}\psdot(P0)
  \pnode([offset=1]{B}A){P1}\psdot(P1)
  \pnode([nodesep=2,offset=1]{B}A){P}\psdot(P)
  \psline(A)([nodesep=2]{B}A) \psline[linestyle=dashed](P0)(P)
  \psline(A)([offset=1]{B}A)  \psline[linestyle=dashed](P1)(P)

  \pnode([nodesep=2,offset=1,angle=135]{B}A){Q}\psdot(Q)
  \psarc[origin={A}]{->}(A){!5 sqrt}{(P)}{(Q)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @o-O-o Done and Gone

Answer (score 4):

I can say, with some degree of certainty, that it is a typo since `([angle=number]{node1} node2)` has the constraint that the result should be on the virtual line connecting A to B. So an additional angle option would be confusing. The angle is working just fine when you have `([angle=number]node)` syntax :

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}  
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
    \pstGeonode(0,5){B}(3,3){A}
    \pstCircleOA[Radius=\pstDistVal{1},linestyle=dashed]{A}{}
    \psline[linecolor=blue]([angle=-90,nodesep=1]B)
    ([angle=45,nodesep=1.414]A)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the relative point syntax the virtual line from (B) to (A) is the `nodesep` direction and normal to that line at (A) is the `offset` direction.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,pstricks]{standalone}  
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,4)
    \pstGeonode(0,4){B}(3,3){A}
    \pstCircleOA[Radius=\pstDistVal{1},linestyle=dashed]{A}{}
    \psline[linecolor=blue]([nodesep=2]{B}A)(A)([offset=2]{B}A)
    \psline[linecolor=green]([offset=0.1]{B}A)
    \psline[linecolor=green]([offset=0.3]{B}A)
    \psline[linecolor=green]([offset=0.5]{B}A)
    \psline[linecolor=green]([offset=0.7]{B}A)
    \psline[linecolor=green]([offset=0.9]{B}A)
    \psline[linecolor=green]([offset=1.1]{B}A)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]